# Related to making if and else logic simple

Tags: java

Can someone help me or guide me with resources that would help me write this code in a simple way? We are internally storing some values which have a different representation across the company. I was wondering if there is a way in JAVA where I store this value ahead of time with its actual standard values which everyone knows.

For instance,

{

ab -> apple

bc -> ball

cd -> cat

}

In my code, I retrieve ab from the database. Instead of checking each time what ab represent, I can on the fly pass the standard value to some other service.

I'm looking to implement something pass apple instead of ab without the use of if and else statement. I know that I will have to store the standard value and point to the internal value which would be a one time thing of writing.

Something in the direction of an array

instead at index[0] -> 1
I say index[ab] -> apple

So something like: let's say I retrieved a from the database, in the code, I just simply call a convert.(a) which return apple instead..

I can't think of a way ... need some help

Comment: Can you re-edit as your question does not make sense? Clarify.

Comment: If the codes are stored in the database why aren't their "translation" stored in the same table? Otherwise, what you want is a Map<String, String>. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html

Comment: Do you mean something like [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you want to retreive values from a database and transform these values into something you "hard code". This could be achieved be a "HashMap". This Map is able to store key-value-pairs.

This Map has basically this structure: `HashMap<Key, Value>`.
Where `Key` is anything you choose to identify a `Value`.

In your case it would look like this (considering you want to store String-String-pairs):

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

map.put("a","apple");
map.put("b","ball");
map.put("c","cat");
```

This basically says e.g. "take an "a" and associate it with "apple". Those two values do not need to be String. They can be anything: `Integer, Float, Object, MyClass,....`

Now if you want to get the transformation for your a you simply do:

```
map.get("a");
```

This call will return "apple" since you associated apple with it earlier.